# SQL if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

How do you do if statements in sql? i want to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exchange.id userid, exchange.name username, exchange.lastactivity     lastactivity, exchange.id avatar, exchange.id link, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status
FROM buddy
if( buddy.penpalA = 887){
      JOIN exchange ON buddy.penpalA = exchange.id
}ELSE{
      JOIN exchange ON buddy.penpalB = exchange.id
}
LEFT JOIN cometchat_status ON exchange.id = cometchat_status.userid
if( buddy.penpalA = 887){
      WHERE buddy.penpalB =887
}ELSE{
      WHERE buddy.penpalA =887
}    

ORDER BY username ASC
```

Comment: @Yuck, `case` would not be effective here.

Comment: That final IF clause, no matter how many times I read it doesn't make sense. If buddy,penpalA = 887 - then you want penpalB to be checked, otherwise check for penpala to be 887 - that is a bit circular.

Comment: @Andrew: Right, that would necessarily be: `WHERE penpalA = 887 AND penpalB = 887` because the `else` condition would never be met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your `WHERE`s and `ON`s. Note that the parantheses around the `AND`ed comparisons is unnecessary; I did it just to clarify what is happening.

```
SELECT DISTINCT exchange.id userid, exchange.name username,
                exchange.lastactivity lastactivity, exchange.id avatar,
                exchange.id link, cometchat_status.message,
                cometchat_status.status
FROM buddy
JOIN exchange ON (buddy.penpalA = exchange.id AND buddy.penpalA = 887)
              OR (buddy.penpalB = exchange.id AND buddy.penpalA <> 887 AND buddy.penpalB = 887)
LEFT JOIN cometchat_status ON exchange.id = cometchat_status.userid
WHERE buddy.penpalA = 887 OR buddy.penpalB = 887
ORDER BY username ASC
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code above to also join when the `penpalB` is 887, as per my understanding of your comment.

Comment: I have a database with penpalA and penpalB  which is a database which has all friend requests in it, I want to be able to select all the friends of userid 887, bearing in mind that the userid can appear in column penpalA or penpalB, do you get me?

Comment: @Jake, then your question was incorrect. I think your first `ELSE` should be `else if( buddy.penpalA = 887)`. Right? Let me know and I'll provide a solution.

Comment: Hi, im not that mathematical, i just want something like:  if penpalA = 887 then get penpalB details and viceversa only if the status = 1 (which means the friendship has been aprooved

Comment: hi justin, is there anyway we could speak via Gtalk or something as im not quite getting the results im looking for, then we can post the solution here after? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, using Transact-SQL you can structure an IF-ELSE like this:

```
IF a > b
BEGIN
   // do something
END
ELSE
   // do something else
```

Comment: The question is tagged for MySQL. In addition, T-SQL doesn't support `//` style comments. FWIW, it **does** support `/* */`.